# Control of active menu items

Tags: yii2

I'm setting up a small page, so i removed /site/ from the URL. Most pages will be static pages on the site controller, so this looks cleaner.

The menu widget is configured as follows:

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/']],
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/about']],
    ['label' => 'Projects', 'url' => ['/projects']],
];
```

And the config rule is

```
'rules' => [
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
],
```

Now my problem is that my menu item links are no longer marked as active (css `.active`). What controlls this, and how can I change it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved.

Change the menuItems like this

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/'], 'active' => $this->context->route == 'site/index'],
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/about'], 'active' => $this->context->route == 'site/about'],
    ['label' => 'Projects', 'url' => ['/projects'], 'active' => $this->context->route == 'site/projects'],
];
```

Comment: Is there any way to make active from controller name

Comment: If you have a related question, you should [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a separate question and link/mention this question. That way, @Beate can leave an answer on that question (instead of this question, where it shouldn't be)

Comment: @YasarArafath just check it like this ```'active' => Yii::$app->controller->id == 'product'```

Answer (score 3):

You should to use `'url' => [controller/action]` to get this thing done. And this config will be overwrited by you rules. So, and then class `.active` will be added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in_array method to check current URL. In array we need add all urls in which menu is in active state.

```
'active' => in_array($this->context->route,['items/index','items/create','items/update']),
```

If we open List page, create page or update page, Item menu will be active.

We can use Controller id to check current controller

```
'active' => Yii::$app->controller->id == 'items',
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in yii2 for best menu:

```
\yii\widgets\Menu::widget([
    'submenuTemplate' => "\n<ul class='top-nav-menu'>\n{items}\n</ul>\n",
    'activateParents' => false,
    'activeCssClass' => 'active',
    'id' => 'sandwich-menu',
        ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Education'), 'url' => ['/site/education'] ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Entertainment'),
            'url' => '#',
            'items' => [
                ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Games'), 'url' => ['/site/games']],
                ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Music'), 'url' => ['/site/music'] ],
                ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Videos'), 'url' => ['/site/videos'] ],
                ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Chat & Forum'), 'url' => ['/site/forum'] ],
                ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Clubs'), 'url' => ['/site/clubs'] ]
            ]
        ],
        ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'News'), 'url' => ['/site/news']],
        ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Contact'), 'url' => ['/site/gencol'] ]
    ]
])
```

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way or form, does it?

Comment: 'activeCssClass' => 'active' code adds active class for menu

Comment: Well, activeCssClass is '.active' by default. The issue here, on the other hand, is that the menu items are not registered as active when the controller is removed from the url.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as soovorow suggested, it should work with

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/']],
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
    ['label' => 'Projects', 'url' => ['/site/projects']],
];
```

the problem was that the controlled name was not explicit in

```
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/']],
    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/about']],
    ['label' => 'Projects', 'url' => ['/projects']],
];
```